# Unable to create a map of a class in C++

Tags: c++

I'm not able to create a map of a certain class in C++.

Here is an example of what I'm talking about:

```c++
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
 
using namespace std;

class A {
    private:
        string name;
    public:
        A(){}
        A(string name) : name(name){}
        A(A& a) : name(a.name){}
        ~A(){}
 
        string getName() { return name; }
};
 
int main() {
    A a("a_name");
    map<string, A> mapa;
    mapa["a_name"] = a;
 
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile the code, it gives me the following error:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_algobase.h:64,
                 from /usr/include/c++/8/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/8/ios:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/8/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/8/iostream:39,
                 from prog.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_pair.h: In instantiation of ‘struct std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, A>’:
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_map.h:517:10:   required from ‘std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::mapped_type& std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::operator[](std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::key_type&&) [with _Key = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; _Tp = A; _Compare = std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, A> >; std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::mapped_type = A; std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::key_type = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]’
prog.cpp:20:15:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_pair.h:303:17: error: ‘constexpr std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&) [with _T1 = const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; _T2 = A]’ declared to take const reference, but implicit declaration would take non-const
       constexpr pair(const pair&) = default;
                 ^~~~
```

Here is the code in ideone: https://www.ideone.com/sYsxcO

I need the map to save the object itself, and not just a pointer to it (in this case, the `A` objects).

Comment: copy-constructor signature should be `A(const A& a)` instead of `A(A& a)`

Comment: Agreed, but I note that gcc 11 compiles this despite the flawed copy constructor.

Comment: You should follow the rule of 3 or 5 here. Go and implement the move constructor and tell us if the problem remains :)

Comment: @dewaffled Yup, you're right, thank you! I would never think of that on my own. Create the answer that I'll accept it.

Comment: @FinnEggers Since there is no manual resource management going on, the rule of 0 is better. There is no need for explicit copy- or move-ctor.